# Angular 2 watch component property for changes without @Input or @Output

Tags: angular

In Angular 1.x I could use .$watch to watch anything I wanted, however in Angular 2 we have ngOnChanges which is really cool and performant but only watches input and output decorators. However from time to time I really need to watch local properties so that I can emit an event when they change. I remember seeing an article explaining how you can explicitly tell Angular 2 to watch a single property but for the life of me I can't find the article anymore and every search I do just tells me to use the input/output decorators with onChanges. How can I create a watcher for a @ViewChild or other local properties?

For example I have a ngForm, that when it's validation state changes from valid to invalid or vise versa I want to emit the state to another component so it can react. However since my ngForm is a @ViewChild and not a @Input or @Output ngOnChanges doesn't detect the change.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The equivalent to a custom Angular 1 `$watch()` in Angular 2 is to implement lifecycle hook `ngDoCheck()` and perform your own checking.  The Lifecycle Hooks dev guide has [an example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#docheck).

Note that your `ngDoCheck()` method will be called every time change detection runs (just like an Angular 1 watch), so be sure it is implemented as efficiently as possible.

Try to use RxJS (an Observable, Subject, etc.) instead, if possible, as it is  more efficient.  We [used to be able to subscribe to the NgForm's ControlGroup to be notified of changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34615922/215945), but I don't know if that is still available.

Comment: how about ngModelChange?