# Detect property change on Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What is the best approach of reacting to property changes at a component level? What I am looking for is a way to trigger a method each time one of the properties of a component changes. Here's a single component:

```
@Component({selector: 'component', template: '{{name}} {{number}}'})
class singleComp {
  name: string = 'Old';
  number: number = 1;

  changeProperties() {
    this.name = 'New';
    this.number = 2;
  }

  changesDetected() {
    console.log('Changes detected');
  }
}
```

In the example above, the singleComp has two properties `name` and `number`. This is a simple example. Calling `changesDetected()` from `changeProperties()` is not an option as the component may have multiple methods modifying the component's properties. I don't want to call `changesDetected()` at the end of each method that modifies a property because that will mean multiple calls from multiple methods.

I have tried to detect changes using `OnChanges` and `AfterContentChecked`, but none of them really work. Those methods detect changes on the `@input` properties but not detect the changes of "native" properties inside a component.

Shortly described, I am looking for a way to fire the `changesDetected()` each time an internal property of the component is modified.

**edit**

It is true that `ngDoCheck` detects internal changes. However, once implemented it will also detect changes on external components and it is not really useful at a component level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 watch component property for changes without @Input or @Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111323/angular-2-watch-component-property-for-changes-without-input-or-output)

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović, I wrote on the question that I am not looking for `@input` change detection. What interest me is related to internal changes on the native properties of a component.

Comment: Even though `ngDoCheck` do check for internal property changes, it is also been triggered each time changes are made on external components. This is not useful when you want to scope change detection to a component level.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) or this use case.

hat is the best approach of reacting to property changes at a component level? What I am looking for is a way to trigger a method each time one of the properties of a component changes. Here's a single component:

```
@Component({selector: 'component', template: '{{name}} {{number}}'})
class singleComp {
  name: string = 'Old';
  number: number = 1;
  private propertiesChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  private _score: number;

  get score():boolean {
    return this._score;
  }

  set score(s:number) {
    this._score = s;
    this.propertiesChanged.emit(s);
  }

  constructor() {
     this.propertiesChanged.subscrive(() => this.changesDetected());
  }
  changeProperties() {
    this.name = 'New';
    this.number = 2;
    this.propertiesChanged.emit({}); // you can pass any object here, chanegd properties as well.
  }

  changesDetected() {
    console.log('Changes detected');
  }
```

}

You can also emit change event in the setter of these properties, choose whatever makes more sense in your use case. see the score property for instance

Comment: I like your approach but it requires to implement a new code line inside each method that modifies the property. Has the same effect as calling the  `changesDetected()` method directly.
Could it be possible to attach listeners to the component's properties directly and react each time they are modified?

Comment: If you implement this with properties setter you dont need to put this everywhere you only need to put this in setter.