# How to check in a component input values is changed or not in angular

Tags: angular

In angular i want to check the component containing any input value is changed or Not.

Example.

i have a page with 5 controls (3 text box and 2 drop downs )
if the value got changed on textbox or drop down,i want to identify that is any value is changed or it is as previous.

please help me,if any one can..

Comment: Are you using Angular's forms?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? At least you can include a sample code.

Comment: yes i am using angular

Comment: If you are using forms, you can use [`valueChanges`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges) method to subscribe to the form's value changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for changes in form in Angular 2 using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982790/how-to-check-for-changes-in-form-in-angular-2-using)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [`ReactiveForms`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ReactiveFormsModule) you can use [`valueChanges`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges) like:

```
this.myFormGroup.valueChanges
 .debounceTime(500) // optional
 .subscribe(data => {
   // do some stuff with `data`
 });
```

Comment: Maxime,How to create myFormGroup .Can you tell me sample code.

Comment: @pushp I suggest you to follow this excellent [Todd Motto's Reactive Form tutorial](https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-reactive), it will learn you the bases of Reactive Forms and its API.

Comment: if I have more than 100 controls and editable  grids in the page at this situation do i have to explicit add these controls into  myFormGroup .

Comment: No you're not forced to do that, you also can add them dynamically in a loop.

Answer (score -1):

In input field write `(ngModelChange)="findchanges(inputValue)"`. Then in ts file get changes of that input field.