# How can I check that a form has unsaved changes before closing ng-modal in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, validation, bootstrap-modal, form-control, ng-modal

I have a modal popup. It has a form-group-like registration form. And it has fields like `text`, `checkbox`, `select`. If the user changes any form controls without saving the form, and then tries to close the modal popup, I would like to show a warning message to force saving changes or leaving the popup.

I've seen [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982790/how-to-check-for-changes-in-form-in-angular-2-using), but I don't understand how it works. Where can I get the form-got-changed status in the `FormIntactChecker` class?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like so

```
form = FormGroup({}); // create your FormGroup here or if you already have it, just check 
if (this.form.dirty) {}
```