# Angular 2: Debounce (ngModelChange)?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to debounce the template directive `(ngModelChange)`?

Or, alternatively, what is the least-painful way to do it a different way?

The closest answer I see is this: [How to watch for form changes in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615425/how-to-watch-for-form-changes-in-angular-2)

So, for example, I have a text input, I want to get onChange updates, but I want to debounce it down from every keystroke:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a value" name="foo" [(ngModel)]="input.event.value" (ngModelChange)="onFieldChange($event, input)">
```

Debounce `onFieldChange()`

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#search-by-name may be this link will help you

Comment: You could use a debounce decorator, checkout:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61177846/1691423

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**EDIT**

In new version of Angular you can use `updateOn` in `ngModelOption` to set `'blur'` for example. [Link to angular.io documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#properties).

Code example :

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="value"
  [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
  (ngModelChange)="updateOnlyOnBlur($event)">
```

**LEGACY**

Here's the less painful way of debouncing keystrokes if you don't want to use the `formcontrol` approach.

> search.component.html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a value" name="foo" [(ngModel)]="txtQuery" (ngModelChange)="onFieldChange($event)">
```

> search.component.ts

```
    export class SearchComponent {
    
         txtQuery: string; // bind this to input with ngModel
         txtQueryChanged: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
    
         constructor() {
          this.txtQueryChanged
            .debounceTime(1000) // wait 1 sec after the last event before emitting last event
            .distinctUntilChanged() // only emit if value is different from previous value
            .subscribe(model => {
              this.txtQuery = model;
    
              // Call your function which calls API or do anything you would like do after a lag of 1 sec
              this.getDataFromAPI(this.txtQuery);
             });
        }
    
    onFieldChange(query:string){
      this.txtQueryChanged.next(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: See @Willi Mentzel's update to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52977862/467240

Comment: Is it necessary to set the model back to the txtQuery inside the subscription?

Comment: @AugustoBarreto Because he is using two-way binding (a.k.a. "banana in a box" [()] ), it is not necessary. At the point the subscription is setting `this.txtQuery` it has already been updated by the ngModelChange shorthand via the two-way binding

Answer (score 47):

### For RxJs 6+

The chosen answer won't work for RxJs 6+. Here is what you have to change:

The imports have to look like this:

```
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

You need to call `pipe`:

```
// ...
this.txtQueryChanged
   .pipe(debounceTime(1000), distinctUntilChanged())
   .subscribe(model => {
       this.txtQuery = model;
       // api call
   });
 // ...
```

Take a look at [this article](https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/) for further reading.

Answer (score 38):

I've written a little directive to solve this.

How to use it:

```
<input [ngModel]="someValue" (ngModelChangeDebounced)="someValue = $event">
```

You can optionally set a debounce time (default is 500):

```
[ngModelChangeDebounceTime]="200"
```

The directive itself:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModelChangeDebounced]',
})
export class NgModelChangeDebouncedDirective implements OnDestroy {
  @Output()
  ngModelChangeDebounced = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input()
  ngModelChangeDebounceTime = 500; // optional, 500 default

  subscription: Subscription;
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  constructor(private ngModel: NgModel) {
    this.subscription = this.ngModel.control.valueChanges.pipe(
      skip(1), // skip initial value
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      debounceTime(this.ngModelChangeDebounceTime)
    ).subscribe((value) => this.ngModelChangeDebounced.emit(value));
  }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-0-0-rc-1-y2q2ss

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to add `debounceTime` while doing http call you can use `Subject` which is very easy to use . Which is also explained in angular2 [tutorial - HTTP](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#search-by-name).

Answer (score 3):

I've accomplished that using a Subject.

```
public onModelChangeSubject = new Subject<string>();
```

Then on the ngOnInit of the component, I added:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.onModelChangeSubject.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(_ => {
    this.doSomething();
  });
}
```

And finally, in the template, I just made a small change in the ngModelChange event:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="myValue" (ngModelChange)="onModelChangeSubject.next()">
```