# Angular 2 - too many observables to subscribe in ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, ngoninit

I have a huge model-driven form which it's fields may affect each other's behavior, For example:

If value of field A changes, Value of field B should be obtained from server,Or if value of field C changes, Field D should be disabled & etc.

In order to detect the changes I use **valueChanges**:

```
this.form.controls['a'].valueChanges.subscribe(data=>{
    //do some staff
});
this.form.controls['b'].valueChanges.subscribe(data=>{
    //do some staff
});
.
.
.
```

(Note that I can't say `this.form.valueChanges` because my form has about 50 fields). Everything looks fine but this approach makes my `ngOnInit()` a little messy. My question is:

Is there any better/more efficent solution for situations like this?Subscribing too many observables in ngOnInit doesn't make any problems?How can I improve my code?

Answer (score 1):

It will be cleaner to use angular [`event binding`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding) on the template. Combine that with `ngModel` for bidirectional data-binding, and it can make your component code much cleaner.

For example:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="a" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" (change)="doSomething($event)">
```

You can do `event binding` in Angular2 for DOM events like `change`, `click`, `keyup`, `blur` etc.

**Edit:**

- `change` gets fired only on clicking outside the input textbox.
- `keyup` is a better option compared to `change`.

See this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1glzZEvFmO08IUwTIbAQ?p=preview) to compare the difference.

Comment: using (change) will be delayed,look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34616143/4221872

Comment: Actually `change` event is fired only on `blur`. If you want the event to be fired as you type then you can use `keyup`, the delay between `keyup` and `valueChanges.subscribe` is negligible. I have put together a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1glzZEvFmO08IUwTIbAQ?p=preview) for you to verify this. [http://plnkr.co/edit/1glzZEvFmO08IUwTIbAQ?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/1glzZEvFmO08IUwTIbAQ?p=preview)

Comment: The main problem of change is working with select tags,If I `console.log()` the value of a `<select>` formControl in the `(change)` method,It shows me it's previous value. So I used valueChanges

Comment: Well.. I am not sure how you are testing. Please see the [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1glzZEvFmO08IUwTIbAQ?p=preview). I have added a select element to it now, and you can see that `(change)` gives back the new value!!

Comment: Thanks! I got it ;-)